# How to solve App availability issues for certain users?

Tags: android, flutter, google-play, google-play-console

I get complaints from users that they can't download my app
They see a message that the app is not available for their device

They've been checking every day for the past two weeks
In my application minSdkVersion 21 targetSdkVersion 33 is set

Can you tell me why the app is not available for some users?

I tried to change all the distribution settings in the Google console but no change for the users

Comment: Post you manifest.  You may be requiring features that their device doesn't support